# pass values from Recyclerview to Fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view which display users informations in rows ,every row has 
TextView to display name and another textview to display the job; I used interface to handle OnitemClick in recyclerview to launch a fragment,it will display the user data name and job, I tried to use bundles to pass the values from recyclerview adapter to the fragment but the bundle is always null,

here is my Adapter class

```
public class AuthorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AuthorAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Realm mRealm;
private RealmResults<AuthorInfo> results;
private LaunchFragment lanch;

public AuthorAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<AuthorInfo> realmResults, Realm realm, LaunchFragment mLaunch) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    results = realmResults;
    mRealm=realm;
    lanch=mLaunch;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view,lanch);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    AuthorInfo current = results.get(position);


    holder.name.setText(current.getName());
    holder.job.setText(current.getJob());


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return results.size();
}




public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView name;
    TextView job;
    ImageView image;
    CheckBox checkbox;

    ItemClickListener itemclicklistener;

    LaunchFragment launchFragment;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView,LaunchCards listener) {
        super(itemView);

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        job = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_job);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_author);
        checkbox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkbox.setOnClickListener(this);
        lanunchFragment=listener;
        image.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener ic) {
        this.itemclicklistener = ic;

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        Fragment fragmentGet = new FragmentCard();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name",results.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName());
        fragmentGet.setArguments(bundle);

        lanunchFragment.onMark(getAdapterPosition());

    }
}
```

}

and here is the Fragment class

```
public class FragmentCard extends Fragment {
TextView name;
TextView job;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_fragment,container,false);

    Bundle arguments=getArguments();
    if (arguments !=null){
    String nameUser=arguments.getString("name");
    String jobUser=arguments.getString("job");

    name= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.get_author);
    job= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.get_job);

    name.setText(nameUser);
    job.setText(jobUser);}

    return view;
}
```

}

so any ideas why is bundle always null?

Comment: can u share the code of   lanunchFragment.onMark(getAdapterPosition());

Comment: @AdeelTurk  this is the code of lauunchFragment.onMark   LaunchCards launchCards=new LaunchCards() {@Override public void onMark(int position) {showFragmetLaunch(); } };     and this showFragmentlaunch method :     private void showFragmetLaunch() {
 FragmentCard fragment=new FragmentCard();
FragmentManager maneger=getSupportFragmentManager(); FragmentTransaction transaction=maneger.beginTransaction();    transaction.add(R.id.dump,fragment,"AuthorFrag");transaction.commit();}